# Same style class for different components in Angular 6

Tags: css, angular, angular6

I have css class which needs to be added to three different component(for example) which might not require for other components of our application.
which one would be the best approach.

1. add that css class to style.css (global css)and use it or
2. add it to three different component specific style sheet as it is not used anywhere in the application(is this considered as code duplicate ?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would say that adding it to the global styles is just fine for this purpose. View encapsulation is cool, but the cascading part of CSS is still something that we're supposed to take advantage of...just as long as you're still cognizant of keeping styles organized and not too high of specificity.

Conversely, if you knew all three components would share parent component, you could turn off view encapsulation for that component and add the class there, which is essentially the same as adding to global styles with the difference being the style would only be loaded when the component is loaded.

You could also use `::ng-deep`on a parent component to target its children. Sass brings other solutions, but it doesn't look like you're using .scss files.

Comment: another good thing might be adding an specific class as an anchor, so that only elements with a certain class will receive the styles needed, with that you eliminate the chance that another element might get them applied, like `div.anchor-class div { *your styles* }` `div.anchor-class .my-sub-class { *more styles* }`